# Installing CPLEX causes a problem in MacOS Big Sur

Tags: java-web-start, cplex, macos-big-sur, java-runtime-compiler

When I try to download CPLEX no-cost academic edition from the IBM website, the download does not automatically start and it states "If Download Director does not start install / re-install Download Director."

When trying to install download director it gives an error of "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports javaws."
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

BigSur is not yet supported but you may try to get the beta that supports BigSur as said in https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=4969f0e5-367b-44e0-a679-a7e4f46e8a9a&CommunityKey=ab7de0fd-6f43-47a9-8261-33578a231bb7&tab=digestviewer#bm4969f0e5-367b-44e0-a679-a7e4f46e8a9a

> "The fix for BigSur is ready as a beta - please drop a mail to
> cos-ai-support@wwpdl.vnet.ibm.com with your academic email, and I will
> send you a download link."